# Angular - Type Pipe does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, pipe

I am attempting to create a custom pipe that would return a sum of an array in a table, but for whatever reason, Angular is complaining about my pipe not having an 'emod' property.

My pipe:

```js
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'fieldSum',
  pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class FieldSumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], attr: string): number {
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
  }
}
```

My module:

```js
import { SomeComponent} from './some.component';
import { SomeRoutingModule} from './some-routing.module';
import { FieldSumPipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/fieldsum.pipe';
// Other imports...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SomeRoutingModule,
        FieldSumPipe, // other imports removed for brevity
    ],
    declarations: [
        SomeComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        FieldSumPipe
    ]
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

My component HTML:

```js
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-lg" [mfData]="tableData" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="10">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>Profit</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
            <td>{{ item.Id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Something }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Profit }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ mf.data | fieldSum:'Profit' }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

VS Code is claiming that `The pipe 'fieldSum' could not be found`, but it does compile everything successfully and it manages to open in browser. However, when I click on whatever is supposed to load my component, the console displays an error.

```js
core.js:4442 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type FieldSumPipe does not have 'ɵmod' property.
Error: Type FieldSumPipe does not have 'ɵmod' property.
    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1855)
    at recurse (core.js:24235)
    at recurse (core.js:24246)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:24231)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:24345)
    at Compiler_compileModuleSync__POST_R3__ (core.js:27135)
    at Compiler_compileModuleAsync__POST_R3__ [as compileModuleAsync] (core.js:27140)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (router.js:3506)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:44)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:34)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27533)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

I am not sure if it's related in any way, but my SomeModule is lazy loaded in the AppRoutingModule.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'Whatever',
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'some',
        loadChildren: () =>
        import('./some/some.module').then((m) => m.SomeModule),
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Try remove this @Injecatbel in pipe. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As it turns out, the solution was to to put the FieldSumPipe in the `declarations` and `exports` of my module rather than the `imports`.

```js
import { SomeComponent} from './some.component';
import { SomeRoutingModule} from './some-routing.module';
import { FieldSumPipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/fieldsum.pipe';
// Other imports...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SomeRoutingModule, // other imports removed for brevity
    ],
    declarations: [
        FieldSumPipe,
        SomeComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        FieldSumPipe
    ]
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

Answer (score 48):

TL;DR: `rm -rf .angular`

I had this suddenly on an old and working project, also for older commits. Nothing worked for me:

- removed node_modules and ran `npm i`
- run again `ng s`
- restart my computer

I had some odd clues (worked on different port, worked when I removed my folder and recloned the repo) that led my working solution: remove `.angular` folder (containing cache folder)

Comment: This worked for my scenario: we are on angular 13 and switched to using pnpm and was getting the emod errors.

Comment: When your messing with npm packages and emo errors appear... this is it ;) thanks

Comment: I'm using yarn. installed a new package (`ng-mocks`). Thanks for sharing this @arielhasidim

Comment: This answer worked for me. I am using Node 18 and it was throwing the following error: Type RxReactiveFormsModule does not have 'ɵmod' property

Answer (score 14):

You must add it only in the declarations.

Like this:

```js
import { SomeComponent} from './some.component';
import { SomeRoutingModule} from './some-routing.module';
import { FieldSumPipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/fieldsum.pipe';
// Other imports...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SomeRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        SomeComponent,
        FieldSumPipe
    ]
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same weird error with missing "emod" property - just with a Service. I forgot that services go into Providers array, and not Imports, in the Module. I guess they could write a better error message.

[image: services belongs in providers array]

Answer (score 12):

I got a similar error and fixed it merely by restarting the `ng serve` server.

(Pardon I'm not answering the original question but this might be useful for others who search for the error and arrive here.)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
rimraf node_modules && npm i
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I **imported the wrong type**. Instead of

```
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
```

I imported

```
import { MatExpansionPanel } from '@angular/material/expansion';
```

which gave me this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **FieldSumPipe** in providers section, not in declarations section

Answer (score 0):

Import BrowserAnimationsModule,or only once, preferably in your root module

Answer (score 0):

in my case I have done the following

- removed node_modules
- remove bower_components
- ran npm i --force
- run again ng s

Answer (score 0):

If you add components, dircetives or pipes in imports array of a module instead of declaration, you will get this error

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue because of the missing quote mark in the HTML file. I accidentally put `<use xlink:href=#eye"">` instead of `<use xlink:href="#eye">`.