# Does not have 'ɵmod' property errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have been stuck on this for a day now.

On a clean repo, after doing an pnpm install, then an ng serve, you end up with this error in the console

> ...does not have 'ɵmod' property

This can happen with any module and the workaround below work for any module. NOTE: This can also happen if you have imported something other than a Module - there is nothing wrong with my imports in this case.

Workarounds:

1. restart ng serve **or** run ng build twice
2. See [ngx-leaflet-draw: Importing module which does not have a ɵmod property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67202351/1926476) (but I couldn't get ngcc to actually do anything - so that doesn't work for me - worth pointing that my repo has multiple projects)

While those workarounds may be adequate for a development environment, in a CI environment, you have to essentially have ng build twice to workaround the issue (which comes at a cost).

My solution in my CI build at the moment is to build twice (Scary to tell a compiler, if you don't get it right the first time, have another go...)

How do you go about finding the root cause of this issue? (So I can have a single ng build step in my CI build).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Type Pipe does not have 'ɵmod' property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66005232/angular-type-pipe-does-not-have-%c9%b5mod-property)

Comment: Sadly no. This post relates to 'importing something other than a module' which I mention. In their case, a code fix was needed. In my case, no code fix is required, I need to build twice...

Comment: BTW, if I do a production build (only once), I end up with 'Cannot read property 'selectors' of null' error. (Building twice = no error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue for me is that I was using **pnpm** as package manager. Unfortunately, pnpm doesn't seem to play nicely with ngcc - pnpm uses hard-links in the node_modules folder. I have [raised an issue](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/3686) with pnpm.

It turns out that pnpm can also cause the following issues (all fixable by running ng serve or build again):

- TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindingStartIndex' of null
- An error occurred during the build: Error: Tried to overwrite ... __ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed